# C# Misma aplicación corriendo en otro equipo en red

Tags: c#, mysql, networking

Buenas tardes a todos,

Tengo programada una aplicación en C# y me gustaría que solamente se pueda instalar en un equipo o en dos de la misma red.
Esta aplicación lee datos de una base de datos MySQL, la idea sería instalarla en el PC "A" pero si se instala en el equipo "B" que no corra por que el PC "A" ya está corriendo la aplicación y por tanto conectado a la base de datos.

¿Alguna idea? No se me ocurre como lograrlo!!!!

Mil gracias a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guardar el inicio y cierre de sesión para cada PC donde consultas la BD y preguntes si alguien inicio sesión pero no se ha cerrado entonces no permitir el inicio de la aplicación. Algo así como un flag.